# How to update reversed code of an updated application?

Tags: android, apk

A few months ago I started to reverse engineer an Android app, and i have pretty much progress in it, but it's updated weekly. How should i go about updating the reversed code?

I searched for ways to record and replay the refactorings, but I've found nothing about it, and I also realized it's not a good way if i use deobfuscation in jadx (just to make some class names valid, because a lot of them would start with numbers..), because the new names of methods and classes are based on counting them.

The main goal is not to have code which I can use to rebuild the app, I only need it to understand the inner workings of it and to know where and how to hook with Xposed. The goal now is to update my project with the changes of the new version.

I'm currently using Android Studio for reversing android apps, and jadx 0.7.1 to decompile them.